# Tcl: List element in braces followed by "]]" instead of space

Tags: tcl

Error: listelement in braces followed by "]]" instead of spaces

Code:

```
create_pattern  -layers  { [list [list {vertical_layer: m12} [list width: $m12_width] [list pitch: $m12_pitch] {spacing: interleaving}  {trim: false } {track_alignment: track}]] 
[list [list {vertical_layer: m11} [list width: $m11_width] [list pitch: $m11_pitch] {spacing: interleaving}  {trim: false } {track_alignment: track}]] 
}
```

Comment: The outermost braces are preventing variable substitution. You might want `create_pattern -layers [list ...]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is that you've enclosed all that list construction in braces, which turns it into something else (that you probably don't want; the literal list parser treats `[list` as an actual word of the list, and gets confused by `}]]` as it is *deliberately* stupid code so that it is also predictable code). The amount of nesting that is going on is quite confusing, and distinctly unexpected.

I'm guessing that you'd be better off with a helper procedure to generate the component structure and then using that:

```
proc LayerDescriptor {id width pitch} {
    # I'm not sure that this is right, but it would be a lot less surprising than a list of lists of lists of things
    return [list \
        [list vertical_layer: $id] \
        [list width: $width] \
        [list pitch: $pitch] \
        {spacing: interleaving} \
        {trim: false } \
        {track_alignment: track}]
}

create_pattern -layers [list \
    [LayerDescriptor "m12" $m12_width $m12_pitch] \
    [LayerDescriptor "m11" $m11_width $m11_pitch]]
```

Note the use of backslashes to quote all the newlines. They're important here.

Comment: for m12 it is working but if i want horizontal layer for m11. for eg i want to write code:  create_pattern  -layers  { [list [list {vertical_layer: m12} [list width: $m12_width] [list pitch: $m12_pitch] {spacing: interleaving}  {trim: false } {track_alignment: track}]] 
[list [list {horizontal_layer: m11} [list width: $m11_width] [list pitch: $m11_pitch] {spacing: interleaving}  {trim: false } {track_alignment: track}]] 
}